# How to display search suggestions from Elasticsearch Phrase Suggester with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to display the first 10 options from the options array from the Suggestion object from ES Phrase Suggester using AngularJS, but stumped....

This outputs the first element in the options array:

```
{{suggestions.options[0].text}}
```

The text is the actual suggestion.

Output from Dev Console in Chrome:

```
suggest: {,…}
phraseSuggestion: [{text: "pytho", offset: 0, length: 5, options: [{text: "python", score: 0.12858662}]}]
0: {text: "pytho", offset: 0, length: 5, options: [{text: "python", score: 0.12858662}]}
length: 5
offset: 0
options: [{text: "python", score: 0.12858662}]
0: {text: "python", score: 0.12858662}
text: "pytho"
```

How do I access:

```
options: [{text: "python", score: 0.12858662}]
```

in my Html template and display the first  5 to 10 options in the array.

Comment: I can't understand, you access it with `{{suggestions.options[0].text}}`

Comment: @Michelem yes I understand that, what I'm trying to do is list 5 - 10 options instead of just 1, which is all that code displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have for example the JSON output like this and you want to display the first 2 option item you can do this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/6merubbj/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <p ng-repeat="option in out.options | limitTo:2">{{option.text}} - {{option.score}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.out = {
        "options": [{
            "text": "python",
                "score": 0.12858662
        }, {
            "text": "linux",
                "score": 0.12858662
        }, {
            "text": "php",
                "score": 0.12858662
        }, {
            "text": "js",
                "score": 0.12858662
        }, {
            "text": "java",
                "score": 0.12858662
        }]
    };

}]);
```

Comment: thank you very much! Still learning Angular - it seems awesome - knowing how to use it is half the battle!